# How Can I check the Uniqueness of CKEditor field?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ckeditor

**Steps**

- I have a field for storing Html in my database which is linked to CKEditor.
- When user stores the data it is stored as new entry.
- I want, if there is already the same data in my column, then it should inform me, Can it be possible?

*Note: I want to identify the similarity in in Ckeditor output source which gets stored in database.*

**Expected result**
I must be aware that same data already exists in my table, so I can link it rather than adding to avoid redundancy and repetition!

I am really not sure whether it is possible or not!